# sql oracle - update using select

Tags: sql, oracle, select

I'm having problems updating a column in one of my tables. I have a table called ORDERS, I added a new column to the table that represents the total cost of an order. I get the total cost by using a query that calculates the cost. Now I'm trying to use update using that select query to fill that column in the table. This is what I have:

```
update ORDERS
set TOTAL_COST = (
select sum((p.COST*i.QUANTITY)*(1-o.DISCOUNT))+delivery(o.DELIVERY) as TOTAL_COST
from PRODUCT p, ITEM i, ORDERS o
where p.ID_PRODUCT = i.ID_PRODUCT and i.ID_ORDER = o.ID_ORDER
group by o.ID_ORDER, o.DISCOUNT, o.DATE, o.DELIVERY);
```

My query returns the total cost of every order and that is what I want to have in my table. I get an "single-row subquery returns more than one row" error.
I don't know what I'm doing wrong, any suggestions??

Answer (score 2):

In order for your UPDATE to work, the subquery (SELECT SUM...) needs to return a single row for each order. But according to the  error message, it returns more than one row for certain.

The main problem certainly is that there's no predicate that would relate the current row to be update to the subquery. So you at least need to add something like this to the subquery:

```
o.ID_ORDER = ORDERS.ID_ORDER
```

Furthermore, the GROUP BY clause tends to produce more than one row for the UPDATE. It needs to be reduced to o.ID_ORDER only.

The third problem is the delivery cost, which should be summed but added at the end. So they have to be moved out of the subquery:

```
update ORDERS
set TOTAL_COST = (
  select sum((p.COST*i.QUANTITY)*(1-o.DISCOUNT)) as TOTAL_COST
  from PRODUCT p, ITEM i, ORDERS o
  where o.ID_ORDER = ORDERS.ID_ORDER and p.ID_PRODUCT = i.ID_PRODUCT and i.ID_ORDER = o.ID_ORDER
  group by o.ID_ORDER
) + delivery(DELIVERY);
```

Comment: I've made a further fix and moved the delivery cost out of the subquery.

Comment: thanks for your help, but I don't think the problem is can be solved it this way, I'm better of just creating a new table